# How to submit multiple values from a single jQuery-TokenInput as Name/Value pairs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tokeninput

I'm trying to figure something out that is beyond my skill set, so bear with me.

What I'm trying to do is let users fill out a profile that allows them to select up to four cities from a Livesearch input. I then want to use those city values separately, from storing in a database to passing around as url parameters.

How do I get them out of what seems to be a comma-delimited value string and give them their own names?

Example.

If they selected New York, Chicago, Miami and Dallas, then I get;

```
<input type="text" id="Locations" name="Locations" value="New York,Chicago,Miami,Dallas">
```

What I'd like is;

```
name="city1" value="New York"
name="city2" value="Chicago"
name="city3" value="Miami"
name="city4" value="Dallas"
```

Script;

```
<input type="text" id="Locations" name="Locations" />
<button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>    

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#Locations").tokenInput([    
<?php include 'city-list.php'; ?>
], {
tokenLimit:4    
});
});
</script>
```

Everything works, I just need to separate the values when the form is submitted and I was thinking maybe as hidden fields. I've looked around and I just cant find anything that helps. Anything would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the `tokenValue` parameter, which can be passed a function.

From a technical point of view, I'd suggest using [JSON](http://www.w3schools.com/json/) to contain the information you want to send. (I don't know what you're doing with it afterwards, you can adjust this example as required.)

Try something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#Locations").tokenInput([    
<?php include 'city-list.php'; ?>
], {
tokenLimit:4,    

tokenValue: function(param, el){
                var token = {   "name" : //Do something clever here to generate the names you want. You can get the city name of the token under param.name.
                                "value" : param.name,
                            };
                return JSON.stringify(token);
                }

});
});
</script>
```

N.B. I wasn't completely clear on what values you wanted to use for your 'name'. Hopefully you can adapt this example appropriately!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I don't like seeing unanswered questons.

It seems the OP just wants to separate a comma delimited string when the form is submitted.

You can do that in your PHP script by exploding the string into an array.

```
$cityArray = explode(',', $cityString);
```

That will separate the values into a PHP array which you can then do with as you like.